# Python script not functioning as intended

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ctypes

I have a Python script that is not functioning as intended. The goal is to produce a Tkinter window with the following grid of widgets in a frame with 12 equally-sized columns that scale to fit the window:

- Row 1: Textbox occupying 5 columns, image occupying 2 columns, textbox occupying 5 columns
- Row 2: Two textboxes occupying 6 columns each.

The first row must be minimum height necessary to fit the image. The second row height must occupy the rest of the window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from ctypes import windll
import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
quitapp = False
maxscreens = 1
lookups = ['AVG', 'BTC', 'ETH', 'USDT']
domesticdict = {}

def show_data(data):
    def search_text(event=None):
        # Clear previous highlights
        text_widget.tag_remove("highlight", "1.0", tk.END)

        # Get the search query
        search_query = search_entry.get().upper()

        if search_query:
            start_pos = "1.0"
            instance_count = 0
            first_instance_pos = None

            while True:
                start_pos = text_widget.search(search_query, start_pos, stopindex=tk.END)
                if not start_pos:
                    break

                if not first_instance_pos:
                    first_instance_pos = start_pos

                instance_count += 1

                end_pos = f"{start_pos}+{len(search_query)}c"
                text_widget.tag_add("highlight", start_pos, end_pos)
                start_pos = end_pos

            text_widget.tag_config("highlight", background="yellow", foreground="black")

            if first_instance_pos:
                text_widget.see(first_instance_pos)

            result_label.config(text=f"Found {instance_count} instances.")
    data_window = tk.Toplevel()
    data_window.title("Domestic Sources for Binance Tokens")

    # search entry button
    search_entry = tk.Entry(data_window)
    search_entry.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=5)
    search_button = tk.Button(data_window, text="Search", command=search_text)
    search_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=5)
    result_label = tk.Label(data_window, text="")
    result_label.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=5)
    data_window.bind("<Return>", search_text)  # Bind the search_text function to the Enter key

    # Create a frame to hold the Text and Scrollbar widgets
    frame = tk.Frame(data_window)
    frame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    # Create the Text widget
    text_widget = tk.Text(frame, wrap=tk.WORD, background='black', foreground='white')
    text_widget.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    # Create the Scrollbar widget
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame)
    scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

    # Link the Scrollbar to the Text widget
    text_widget.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command=text_widget.yview)

    for key, value in data.items():
        text_widget.insert(tk.END, f"{key}: {value}\n")

    data_window.mainloop()

def on_image_click(event, data):
    show_data(data)

def create_tkinter_window():
    global domesticdict
    # Create the main window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Crypto Monitor")
    root.state('zoomed')

    fontname = 'Courier'
    fontsize = 14

    frame = tk.Frame(root, background='black', padx = 0, pady = 0)
    frame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    frame.grid()

    # Create the text boxes
    text_box_topleft = tk.Text(frame, font=(fontname, fontsize), wrap=tk.WORD, height = 7, foreground="white", background='black', bd=20, highlightthickness=0)
    text_box_topright = tk.Text(frame, font=(fontname, fontsize), wrap=tk.WORD, height = 7, foreground="white", background='black', bd=20, highlightthickness=0)
    text_box_topright2 = tk.Text(frame, font=(fontname, fontsize+10), wrap=tk.WORD, height=7, foreground="white",
                                background='black', bd=20, highlightthickness=0)
    text_box_left = tk.Text(frame, font=(fontname, fontsize), wrap=tk.WORD, foreground="white", background='black', bd=20, highlightthickness=0)
    text_box_right = tk.Text(frame, font=(fontname, fontsize), wrap=tk.WORD, foreground="white", background='black', bd=20, highlightthickness=0)

    # load the logo
    image_file = "Crypto Monitor.png"
    image = Image.open(image_file)
    new_width = 500
    aspect_ratio = float(image.height) / float(image.width)
    new_height = int(new_width * aspect_ratio)
    image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.LANCZOS)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    image_label = tk.Label(frame, image=photo, background='black', width=new_width)
    image_label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: on_image_click(event, domesticdict))

    # Position the text boxes using the grid geometry manager
    text_box_topleft.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
    image_label.grid(row=0, column=5, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
    text_box_topright.grid(row=0, column=7, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
    text_box_topright2.grid(row=0, column=9, columnspan=3, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
    text_box_left.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=6, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
    text_box_right.grid(row=1, column=6, columnspan=6, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")

    # Configure the grid to resize with the window
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=5)
    for i in range(0, 12): frame.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

    # threading.Thread(target=mainfunction, args=(text_box_topleft, text_box_topright,
    #                                             text_box_left, text_box_right, text_box_topright2)).start()

    def on_close():
        global quitapp
        quitapp = True
        root.destroy()
        sys.exit()

    # Set the custom callback function for the "X" button
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)

    try: root.mainloop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt: pass

create_tkinter_window()
```

This seems like it would be very simple to do, but Python seems to be ignoring my columnspan and columnconfigure weights and assigning whatever column widths it wants to, and the grid exceeds the window size.

Comment: You called both `frame.pack(...)` and `frame.grid()` and the later will override the former, so the frame will not expand to fill the window. Remove `frame.grid()`.  Also set `width=1` for all the text boxes initially and add `uniform=1` (optional) to `frame.grid_columnconfigure(...)`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).